# include тупо вставляет содержимое файла?

Tags: php, include

Всем привет. Ходил на курсы php и в итоге понял, что вообще ничего не понимаю.
Например код 
**main.php**

```
<?
include 'test1.php';
?>
```

**test1.php**

```
<?
$a=3;
echo $a;
?>
```

Как рассказывали на курсах, php берет все, что внутри test1.php, т.е.

```
<?
$a=3;
echo $a;
?>
```

и помещает на место инклуда в main.php

```
<?
include 'test1.php';
?>
```

В итоге main.php превращается в

```
<?
$a=3;
echo $a;
?>
```

Тут всю понятно, но на самом ли деле php делает именно так? Если, например, взять другой код **main2.php**

```
<?
$b=45;
echo $b;
include 'test1.php';
?>
```

По идее php должен все, что в test1.php поместить в main2.php и на выходе должно получиться

```
 <?
$b=45;
echo $b;
<?
$a=3;
echo $a;
?>
?>
```

Но получаются двойные теги php. Так что же на самом деле делает php? Получается помимо копирования кода, он еще и удаляет двойные теги и где он их удаляет внутри или разбивает код на части типа как?

```
 <?
$b=45;
echo $b;
?>
<?
$a=3;
echo $a;
?>
```

А если, например, во включаемом файле будет html?

**main3.php**

```
<?
$b=45;
echo $b;
include 'test2.php';
$n=39;
echo $n;
?>
```

**test2.php**

```
<h1>привет, мир</h1>
```

Как тогда будет вставлен код? Так, верно? или я все неправильно понимаю?

```
<?
$b=45;
echo $b;
?>
<h1>привет, мир</h1>
<? 
$n=39;
echo $n;
?>
```

Также непонятно, если php с помощью include просто вставляет код, то почему тогда код **main4.php** выведет и $b и $a?

```
<?
include 'test3.php';
$a=49;
echo $a;
?>

**test3.php**
<?
$b=54;
echo $b;
return;
?>
```

Хотя мы же return-ом завершили выполнение кода? Т.е. main4.php должен превратиться во что-то вроде и вывод должен ограничиться только $b (потому что return) ?

```
<?
$b=54;
echo $b;
return;
$a=49;
echo $a;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`include` не столько вставляет файл, сколько выполняет его в текущем контексте. В понятие "контекст" - входят локальные переменные, определенные в файле функции, и т.п.

Однако, в понятие "контекст" не входят скобки php (`<?` и `?>`). Просто потому что эти скобки - это не команды языка, а просто оформление. Оформляется каждый из файлов всегда независимо от других.

Comment: А почему все же в последнем случае (с return-ом) выводит обе переменные (по идее return должен закончить вывод на $b)

Comment: Павел, Вы ошибаетесь, после return в этом файле уже ничего не выполняется. Протестируйте еще раз.

Comment: Опечатка, имел ввиду предпоследний случай
<?
include 'test3.php';
$a=49;
echo $a;
?>

**test3.php**
<?
$b=54;
echo $b;
return;
?>

Comment: С этим примером всё в порядке: return выходит из подключенного файла (как из функции). После чего выполняется остальной код в "родителе". Что Вас смутило?

Comment: а точно все верно

Answer (score 2):

Если **бы** php-шный include работал как банальная текстовая подстановка, не было бы нужды в подключаемом файле ставить открывающий тег `<?php` . Или можно было бы в "родителе" поставить открывающую операторную скобку `{`, а закрывающую `}` поставить в подключаемом файле. Но это не работает!

Да, подключаемый файл наследует контекст: ему видны локальные переменные. Но при этом есть и отличия. Например он не получает родительского namespace.

Короче говоря, подключение файла больше похоже на вызов функции, но только с передачей области видимости переменных.

Answer (score 0):

include позволяет динамически подключать (в зависимости от контекста - то есть по ходу исполнения сценария) необходимый код, например так:

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) 
{
    include "$i.php";
}
```

Дальше можно использовать нужную функцию в нужном месте. Из примера выше следует, что у Вас может быть множество функций, объектов с различными методами и др., разбитых по какому-то принципу в разные файлы php, которые вызываются при помощи include.
Этим include отличается от require, который позволяет включить кусок кода ДО выполнения сценария. Это означает, что если Вы попытаетесь при помощи подобной конструкции

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) 
{
    require "$i.php";
}
```

вызвать нужные функции, то получите по носу fatal error-ом